# SharePoint 2010 - Which template should I use for an intranet?

Tags: site-template

I need to select a root site template for an intranet wih the following requirements:

- SharePoint 2010
- Small company
- Approx 40 users
- Subsites (Probably Site Collections)

  - projects
  - Finance
  - HR
- Requires simple document workflow

What have you used?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Usually in an intranet scenario you also want to be able to customize and control the look and feel of the pages contained within the site collection.
For 2010 I simply create a blank site, enable the publishing infrastructure at the site and site collection level and then for sub sites within this site collection create publishing sites.

If you need a formal workflow approval process use the 'Publishing Site with Workflow' site template for your sites.

However for 40 users you might be able to make do with a team site. The pages wiki library would allow users to edit pages and you won't have the overhead of publishing if you are not too concerned with strict governance.

One more thing is that if all the other sites are to be site collection then I would recommend using the Site Directory template and turning on Self Service Site Collection creation as well. Finally put in a search center in the main top level site collection so that users will have the ability to use custom results pages, people search and scopes.

[Activate Site Directory template](http://msforge.net/blogs/mcpblog/archive/2009/11/24/activate-site-directory-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)
[Manage Self-Service Site Collection Creation](http://notes-sharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2010/08/enabledisable-self-service-site.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the project's budget and time constraints will have a big impact on which direction you take. If time and money are tight then I reckon you can achieve what you have outlined with simple Team Sites, as MichalPisarek said, thus allowing you to spend more time into developing:

- A proper taxonomy using Managed
  MetaData services.
- Custom content types, using MMS fields, and incorporate
  these fields into the Doc Info
  Panels in Office.
- A Document Centre (with content
  organiser) utilising appropriate
  rules enforcing quality metadata.
- A Search Centre, with metadata
  refiners, across all your site
  collections.
- Custom Themes per department so they
  are easily recognised upon first
  glance.
- Custom web parts where you have
  specific business requirements.

But then if you have time and money to burn you can customise Master pages and Page layouts - and in my experience you'll need time and money. I don't believe this exercise has been made substantially easier in 2010, but others may disagree.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making your own version of the Team/Blank Site for instance. Having a custom site def allows you to later staple new features onto it easily without affecting other sites that also uses that template.